# Uninstall PCI device driver

Tags: windows-xp, uninstallation, drivers, pci

I want to uninstall a pci device driver from the computer via c++ code.
Im looking for the same action like right-clicking on a device in the device manager, and clicking 'Uninstall'.
I found a function called `DiUninstallDevice`, but it is available only in Windows 7 and later versions of Windows.
Im using Windows XP. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look the following sample [DevCon](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/DevCon-Sample-4e95d71c) the sample code exits also in WDK that support XP. also in the WDK there is alot of sample of using the DiFX